# What does the "..." (triple dot) notation in arrays mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I don't understand what the `...` notation does exactly.

I tried a simple example with Babel to understand it ([**view the example**](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=let%20myArray%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C%20...18%5D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(myArray)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0Aconsole.log(myArray%5B4%5D)%3B%2F%2F%20undefined%0Aconsole.log(myArray.length)%3B%20%2F%2F%203)), but it seems that:

**ES6 syntax**

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, ...18];

console.log(myArray); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(myArray[4]);// undefined
console.log(myArray.length); // 3
```

is the same as **this ES5 syntax**:

```
"use strict";

function _toConsumableArray(arr) { 
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) { 
        for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) {
             arr2[i] = arr[i];
        }
        return arr2;
     } else { 
        return Array.from(arr); 
     } 
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3].concat(_toConsumableArray(18));

console.log(myArray); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(myArray[4]); // undefined
console.log(myArray.length); // 3
```

**BUT:** What does this code do? Because the output (`console.log`) is the same as in this code (ES5):

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];

console.log(myArray); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(myArray[4]);// undefined
console.log(myArray.length); // 3
```

What does the `...18` notation mean?

Comment: Means nothing, since the _spread operator_ doesn't work with numbers. Maybe you want `...'18'` which is `'1', '8'`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Or `...[18]`!

Comment: What did you expect with this code? (And why...)

Comment: Or maybe, `...Array(18).keys()` ?

Comment: I expect an array 1 to 18, I seen in example that use the same example to `...1000000` to initialize an array

Comment: Then you saw a broken example. That's not at all what the operator does.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `...`([*spread operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) works by returning each value from index `0` to index `length-1`:

As example:

```
[...'18'] // returns ['1', '8']
```

which would be the same as:

```
['18'[0], '18'[1]]
```

---

Now, to get an array from `1` to `18`, you can do this:

```
[...Array(19).keys()].slice(1)
```

Or this with map:

```
[...Array(18)].map(_=>i++,i=1)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's quite irrelevant (in my opinion). OP wants to understand `...`, not create an array 1 to 18

Comment: Well my goal is to understand the new (for me) ES6 syntax, not to do this, but thank you any way. Well, if I do finally this with strings `let myArray = ['1','2','3', ...'18'];` why the console log is now `["1", "2", "3", "1", "8"]` ?

Comment: @AralRoca. Because `'18'` has index `0` and `1`, it will return each value in its positions as parameters

Comment: @AralRoca. Without the `...` (_spread operator_) it would be `['1','2','3','18'[0],'18'[1]]`

Comment: uoooo! Nice. Now is clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to see you understood... I will update my answer with these notes

Comment: *"The ...(spread operator) works by returning each value from index `0` to index `length-1`"* That's not quite correct. The spread "operator" (it's not an operator) works with any **iterable** value. An iterable value is a value that has a `[Symbol.iterator]` property.

Comment: I know, OP is about JavaScript, but just note: the "create array" part is not working in TypeScript: `Type 'IterableIterator<number>' is not an array type`.

Answer (score 7):

The expression `[1, 2, 3, ...18]` is invalid.

You cannot use `...` with a [**Number**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). You can only use `...` with an iterable object like an [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [**String**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) or [**Object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

It is interesting to note that [**Tracur**](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) - another transpiler - throws an error when fed the same code:

> ***TypeError**: Cannot spread non-iterable object.*

I am not intimate with the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) but I think this could be a Babel "bug".

Comment: enumerable is with `.length` right ? String, array. And what `...` do exactly in this cases? thanks :)